# Spring JPA Query validation Error - '(', <expression>, FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea, repository

so I'm having this error on Intellij Idea, but as you can see, it says that it expects a '(', which is exactly what I have after the first "Where" clause.
Do you have any idea about this?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT boardroom " +
"FROM BoardroomEntity boardroom "+
"WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(1) + Case When boardroom.groupLeaderId IN ?1 then 1 else 0 end " +
"       FROM BoardroomAttendeeEntity boardroomAttendee " +
"       WHERE boardroomAttendee.boardroom.id = boardroom.id " +
"       AND boardroomAttendee.attendee.id IN ?1) > 1")
List<BoardroomEntity> findByProfileIdAndAttendeeId(List<Long> attendeesIds);
```

Comment: `IN ?1` is the problem. Perhaps it should be `IN (?1)`? Show us the final query.